# 2sxc How to add Comments in blog app

Tags: 2sxc

I see on github repository a new version of the blog app is in working.
I would to know if it is planned to add a sort of comments management maybe with some configurations, like if the comments would be moderated or not...
If nothing is planned about that how can it be done? 
Is there a guide I can follow? I need to develop an api to store comments data?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments in the blog app should be handled with the discus app, which uses the discus platform.